# Receiving No apps can perform this actions error

Tags: android, android-intent, browser

I am attempting to get my app to offer me a choice of what browser to use. I have assigned the URL to http://google.com. When I run it, I get a 'No apps can perform this actions' error. I'm missing something and i cant figure it out.

```
public class myClass{


static private final String URL = "http://www.google.com";
..
..

implicitActivationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            // Call startImplicitActivation() when pressed
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startImplicitActivation();

            }
        });

private void startImplicitActivation() {


        Log.i(TAG, "Entered startImplicitActivation()");

        Intent baseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND,Uri.parse(URL));

        String title = "Choose Browser";
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(baseIntent, title);

        Log.i(TAG,"Chooser Intent Action:" + chooserIntent.getAction());

        startActivity(chooserIntent);
    }
...
...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To view a Web page, use `ACTION_VIEW`, not `ACTION_SEND`.